# best practice in developing a web-application

Tags: jsp, web-applications

is it the best practice of placing all the scripts use in different pages to be placed in the header file??

I think no because if a page do not uses a particular script and it is still loading and wasting processing time and memory.. 
what is the correct way.. 
please correct me..

Comment: For better maintainability, use External

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one JSP page and only little functionality then use it inline.

If you have lots of JSPs in which you have to add similar functionalities and also if you have to apply lots of functionality

It is better to write all scripts in separate page because it doesn't crowd up the JSP pages and also separate the UI and also if you want to add more scripts in future then it will be easier to open scripts page and do the coding rather then searching all pages and writing the code in all pages

Answer (score 0):

If your web app requires very less (minimal) scripts, then it is better to use them inline. If you need much more scripts or any third party's scripts (like many open source scripts available out on the internet), then you should use a `link` attribute in the `<head></head>`